# linq & distinct, implementing the equals & gethashcode

Tags: c#, .net, linq

so I'm trying to make this work and I can't seem to know why it doesn't work

demo code;

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var myVar = new List<parent >();
        myVar.Add(new parent() { id = "id1", blah1 = "blah1", c1 = new child() { blah2 = "blah2", blah3 = "blah3" } });
        myVar.Add(new parent() { id = "id1", blah1 = "blah1", c1 = new child() { blah2 = "blah2", blah3 = "blah3" } });

        var test = myVar.Distinct();

        Console.ReadKey();

    }
}


public class parent : IEquatable<parent>
{
    public String id { get;set;}
    public String blah1 { get; set; }
    public child c1 { get; set; }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        unchecked // Overflow is fine, just wrap
        {
            int hash = 17;
            // Suitable nullity checks etc, of course :)
            hash = hash * 23 + id.GetHashCode();
            hash = hash * 23 + blah1.GetHashCode();
            hash = hash * 23 + (c1 == null ? 0 : c1.GetHashCode());
            return hash;
        }
    }

    public bool Equals(parent other)
    {
        return object.Equals(id, other.id) &&
            object.Equals(blah1, other.blah1) &&
            object.Equals(c1, other.c1);
    }

}

public class child : IEquatable<child>
{
    public String blah2 { get; set; }
    public String blah3 { get; set; }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        unchecked // Overflow is fine, just wrap
        {
            int hash = 17;
            // Suitable nullity checks etc, of course :)
            hash = hash * 23 + blah2.GetHashCode();
            hash = hash * 23 + blah3.GetHashCode();
            return hash;
        }
    }

    public bool Equals(child other)
    {
        return object.Equals(blah2, other.blah2) &&
            object.Equals(blah3, other.blah3);
    }

}
}
```

anyone could spot my error(s) ?

Comment: What error are you getting? What is the intended behaviour? Executing your code simply displays nothing and exits when a key is pressed.

Comment: @jdmichal, put a break point on console.readkey and look at test variable, it should say count = 1 not 2

Comment: @jdmichal From the description one can safely assume the expectation is that Distinct() returns only one item, but in fact it does not

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to override the `Equals(object)` method:

```
public override bool Equals(object obj) {
    return Equals(obj as parent);
}
```

The `object.Equals` method (unlike `EqualityComparer<T>.Default`) does not use the `IEquatable` interface.  Therefore, when you write `object.Equals(c1, other.c1)`, it doesn't call your `Child.Equals(Child)` method.

You don't absolutely need to do that for `parent` as well, but you **really** should.

Comment: Error 'ConsoleApplication1.parent.Equals(ConsoleApplication1.parent)': no suitable method found to override

Comment: @Fredou: I forgot to add the return type.

Comment: this would need to assume that c1 != null and EqualityComparer would not care, right?

Comment: @Fredou: Your primary `Equals` method needs to check that `other` isn't `null`.

Comment: I have the opposite situation: I've overridden GetHashCode and Equals (one shouldn't really ever override only one of them!) but not implemented IEquatable. When I use the Distinct() extention, LINQ doesn't even call the methods. Is this a case where we are, by design, supposed to repeat ourselves?

Comment: Checked MSDN. And it turns out one has to do both: "To compare a custom data type, you need to implement this interface [IEquatable<T>] and provide your own GetHashCode and Equals methods for the type." I am annoyed that MS keeps duplicating and triplicating, it's hard to know your type will always work! IComparable, IComparer, IEquatable, IEqualityComparer, Equals and GetHashCode - is that enough?!?

Comment: One thing that might be worth pointing out is if you don't override `GetHashCode` then `Distinct()` will not work, or not as expected

Answer (score 3):

Either you do what SLaks suggests, or you use `EqualityComparer<child>.Default` in your `parent` class to use your `IEquatable<child>` implementation:

```
  public bool Equals(parent other)
  {
   return object.Equals(id, other.id) &&
    object.Equals(blah1, other.blah1) &&
    EqualityComparer<child>.Default.Equals(c1, other.c1);
 }
```

Comment: this work, now i need to know what is the best practice, implementing this or SLaks way

Comment: You **really** should override `Equals(object)`.  Otherwise, you're likely to get other nasty surprises.

Comment: should override Equals(object): Agree.

Comment: i wish i could accept 2 answers since this one work too, SLaks one is more bulletproof

Comment: Seems to me parent and child are probably both "entities". Why not derive both from a common base class that models only identity (the ID property), equality and comparison? Then when you need the third and later twenty-second type to do the same thing you don't end up with 23 copies of the code. Having a polymorphic way to identify objects can be really useful to other ends as well, e.g. O/R-mapping, caching, instrumentation/tracing, ...

Answer (score 1):

There are several things to get right here.  If I'm going to implement any aspect of equality in a class such as `GetHashCode`, overriding == or `IEquatable`, I always use the following pattern.

1. Override Equals
2. Override GetHashCode
3. Implement `IEquatable<T>` which means implementing `Equals(T)`
4. Implement !=
5. Implement ==

So, if I had a class named ExpiryMonth with properties Year and Month, this is how that implementation would look.  It's a fairly mindless task now to adapt for other types of classes.

I have based this pattern on several other stackoverflow answers which all deserve credit, but which I haven't tracked along the way.

By always implementing all of these elements together, it ensures proper equality operations in a variety of contexts including dictionaries and Linq operations.

```
    public static bool operator !=(ExpiryMonth em1, ExpiryMonth em2)
    {
        if (((object)em1) == null || ((object)em2) == null)
        {
            return !Object.Equals(em1, em2);
        }
        else
        {
            return !(em1.Equals(em2));
        }
    }
    public static bool operator ==(ExpiryMonth em1, ExpiryMonth em2)
    {
        if (((object)em1) == null || ((object)em2) == null)
        {
            return Object.Equals(em1, em2);
        }
        else
        {
            return em1.Equals(em2);
        }
    }
    public bool Equals(ExpiryMonth other)
    {
        if (other == null) { return false; }
        return Year == other.Year && Month == other.Month;
    }
    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (obj == null) { return false; }
        ExpiryMonth em = obj as ExpiryMonth;
        if (em == null) { return false; }
        else { return Equals(em); }
    }
    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        unchecked // Overflow is not a problem
        {
            var result = 17;
            result = (result * 397) + Year.GetHashCode();
            result = (result * 397) + Month.GetHashCode();
            return result;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

When adding the calculating the hash you might want to try something like

`hash ^= id.GetHashCode();`

Not sure if that is what is causing your issue.

Comment: I believe his hashing is fine - and in any case, if it was bad it would lead to poor performance, not incorrect output (so long as the hash is deterministic, which it clearly is in this case). And the perf problem certainly wouldn't be noticeable with only 2 items. :)