# LINQ Return DISTINCT Values

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-6

I have a LINQ to Entities query that I want to return only unique values of TagID and TagName.

Code:

```
var tags = (from t in _dbContext.TaskRecordDetails.ToList()
                       join tag in _dbContext.Tags on t.TagName equals tag.TagName
                       where t.Period == period
                       select new TagDTO()
                       {
                           TagID = tag.TagID,
                           TagName = tag.TagName
                       });

            return tags.Distinct<TagDTO>();
```

However, duplicate rows are still returned as below. How do I ensure only unique rows are returned?

```
[
    {
        "TagID": 1,
        "TagName": "Level 1",
        "TagDescription": null,
        "IsActive": false
    },
    {
        "TagID": 2,
        "TagName": "Level 3",
        "TagDescription": null,
        "IsActive": false
    },
    {
        "TagID": 3,
        "TagName": "Level 5",
        "TagDescription": null,
        "IsActive": false
    },
    {
        "TagID": 1,
        "TagName": "Level 1",
        "TagDescription": null,
        "IsActive": false
    },
    {
        "TagID": 2,
        "TagName": "Level 3",
        "TagDescription": null,
        "IsActive": false
    }
]
```

Comment: Show us your `TagDTO` class, in particular its `GetHashCode` implementation.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [linq & distinct, implementing the equals & gethashcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4786919/linq-distinct-implementing-the-equals-gethashcode)

Comment: Why do you do a `.ToList()` on `TaskRecordDetails`? Try removing that and the query should be translated to SQL and the Distinct should work.

Comment: @Magnus is right. Remove that `.ToList()`. With that the distinct is evaluated locally and not in database. And worst, with that code you load all table. If you have 100 million rows, you will load then all.

Comment: Without the ToList() I get this error... The entity or complex type 'TagDTO' cannot be constructed in a LINQ to Entities query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your last comment, here is a solution:

```
var tags = (from t in _dbContext.TaskRecordDetails
            join tag in _dbContext.Tags on t.TagName equals tag.TagName
            where t.Period == period
            select tag).Distinct().ToList();

return tags.select(x => new TagDTO
{
    TagID = x.TagID,
    TagName = x.TagName
});
```

Comment: Thank you! Why did this work and not my code? Both very similar.

Comment: It is returning a known entity object (POCO). The error you had was 'The entity or complex type 'TagDTO' cannot be constructed in a LINQ to Entities query' and is related to returning a non POCO object.